# Where comes the $ Function from, when jQuery is not loaded?

Tags: javascript

I recoginzed that i can use `$('span')` even when no js-framework is loaded.

It works in FF, Chrome and Edge. Where does this function come from? I had never read about it. Is it a HTML5 feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an alias for `document.querySelector()` provided by browser's developer tools. This shorthand is not available for page's JS code.

There are more useful dollar-tools, most notably `$0` which contains a reference to DOM element selected in inspector.

Documentation:

- [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference)
- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#Helper_commands)
- [Edge](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console/command-line)